# Find the limit of two given integral sequences

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(I_n)$ be a sequence such that:
$$I_n = \int_0^1 x^{2004}\cos(nx)\,dx$$

I need to find two limits: $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} nI_n$.

By using the substitution $t = nx$ and noticing that $\cos t \in [-1, 1]$, I got the following result:
$$I_n \in \left[ -\frac{1}{2005}, \frac{1}{2005} \right]$$

Now, we can conclude that $(nI_n)$ is unbounded and it diverges. For the first limit, I can guess it is $0$, but I can't come up with a proof.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
I_n=\left.\frac{x^{2004}\sin nx}n\right|_0^1-\frac{2004}n\int_0^1x^{2003}\sin nx\,dx = \frac{\sin n}n-\frac{2004}n\int_0^1x^{2003}\sin nx\,dx,
$$
and one can clearly see that $I_n\to 0$.

From the above, 
$$
n\,I_n=\sin n-{2004}\int_0^1x^{2003}\sin nx\,dx,
$$
so $n\,I_n$ is bounded. We can apply the parts trick again:
$$
n\,I_n=\sin n - 2004\left(-\frac{\cos n}n+\frac{2003}n\int_0^1 x^{2002}\cos nx\,dx  \right).
$$
The expression in brackets goes to zero as $n\to\infty$, so the behaviour of $n\,I_n$ aligns with $\sin n$, and so the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}I_n=\color{red}{0}$ is granted by the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), and

$$ n\,I_n = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2004}\,n\cos(nx)\,dx \stackrel{IBP}{=}\sin(n)-2004\int_{0}^{1}x^{2003}\sin(nx)\,dx=\sin(n)+o(1) $$
by the same reason, hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} n I_n$ does not exist.